# NSDate to display only Date in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitableview

I am able to get NSDate to appear as date only and to show it in textfields to add and edit to core data but in the tableviewcell when using the subtitle style it comes out with both the date and time which I don't need thee time.

Any help is appreciated.

the following code is my NSDateFormatter

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate{
var stringValue: String{
    return self.toString()
}

func toString() -> String {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-YYYY"
    let str = formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    return str
}
}

extension String{
var dateValue: NSDate?{
    return self.toDate()
}

func toDate() -> NSDate? {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-YYYY"
    if let date = formatter.dateFromString(self) {
        return date
    }else{
        // if format failed, Put some code here
        return nil // an example
    }
}
}
```

the following code is the subtitle style.  date is called from cordite

```
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "(ddate)"
```

Comment: Your date format strings are wrong.  But that's not your main problem.

Comment: and this helps me how?

Comment: You're right.  You would have eventually figured that out debugging. ... Except that you apparently don't know how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Found out what I was doing wrong.  I added the following line above the cell.detail.textLabel and it works

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-dd-yyy"
        let dateForText = ddate as? NSDate
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateForText!)
```